# Is there any way to get lazy/cached evaluation in Excel cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In one of our Excel sheets, we have a scenario where every row has a value based on (among other things) the previous rows value. Extremely simplified, `B1` is `=A1*123`, `C1` is `=B1*543` and so on. Obviously, that leads to a lot of calculations when we have many thousands of rows. But the rows are time based data; we only ever insert at or near the end, and it is very rare that we change/update data high up the chain (it only really happens when we discover that someone made a mistake months ago).

The files general performance is poor, and it improves a lot if we remove that column, so we are looking for solutions to prevent this chain of 'to calculate A we need B, B needs C, C needs D, ...' from having to be reevaluated all the time.

Is there a way to let Excel know that the cell only needs to be recalculated in certain circumstances ? We would be happy if we could change recalculating (of that formula/column only) to only happen on save, load or a key press or something like that. But we use other formulas that need instant updating, so we don't just want to deactivate formula recalculation for the whole sheet or file.

Comment: Formulas only calculate if the predecessor changes, unless the formula is volatile.  If, by your own description the ones higher up do not change that often, then this column should not be a drag on your calc times.  Are you using Volatile functions like, INDIRECT or OFFSET in this column?

Comment: What is the size of your table (rows X columns with data)?

Comment: @ScottCraner We do not use INDIRECT or OFFSET anywhere, but some of the data comes from complex formulas. How can I tell if they are volatile ?

Comment: @FDavidov we have about a quarter million rows with 50-100 columns, so between 12.5 and 25 million ... data ;)

Comment: @Torque, no matter how many cells need to be updated, they will all need to be checked (to perform an update if needed). With such size of spreadsheet, I doubt you will be able to get a real fast update every time you make a change in a single cell (which, of course, will have an accumulative effect if you update, for instance, 5 cells in a single row; then, every time you update one single cell you will witness a delay in the response). What you could do is to disable calculations prior to updating the cells of a row (or, alternatively, add a whole row at the end) and then re-enable it.